# Why is the Button in the CardPanel not visible (Sencha gxt)

Tags: gwt, gxt

I don't understand why I don't see my `Button` in the `CardPanel`. On the final page is see no UI components. Maybe I'm missing something...

We're using GXT 2.3.1

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.CardPanel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Foobar implements EntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    CardPanel cpanel = new CardPanel();
    cpanel.setActiveItem(new Button("FooButton1"));
    RootPanel.get().add(cpanel);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `.gwt.xml` file pointing to `Foobar` as an entry point?

Comment: Yes at this point there is no problem. When I add a Button to the RootPanel directly, I see the Button. The CardPanel seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the `CardPanel` but I'm pretty sure you're using it wrong.

Setting the widget "active" can only happen if the widget is already added to the panel. You need to `add()` the widget to the panel before setting it active.

Try this:

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.CardPanel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Foobar implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        CardPanel cpanel = new CardPanel();
        Button btn = new Button("FooButton1")
        cpanel.add(btn);
        cpanel.setActiveItem(btn);
        RootPanel.get().add(cpanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[CardPanel#setActiveItem()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/CardPanel.html#setActiveItem%28com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component%29) method is used to set the active (visible) item in the layout.

It doesn't add the item in the layout. You need to add the items in the layout using [`LayoutContainer#add()`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/LayoutContainer.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) method and at a time only one will be visible.

What `CardPanel` states in JavaDoc?

> This container contains **multiple widgets**, each fit to the container, where only a **single widget can be visible at any given time**. This style is most commonly used for **wizards**, **tab** implementations, etc.

**Note:** This `LayoutContainer` is not suitable of this sample code.

Here is an [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/CardLayoutExampleExtGWT.htm) for `CardLayout`